# How to prevent collisions when generating registration activation keys?

Tags: php, random, passwords, key, activation

I'm working on a big project's registration system.

After successful signup, the server generates some activation key, adds it to user's row and sends it to user by email.  Using some password generator class for this purpose.

The question is (I know that it sounds abstract but I just wonder), how to avoid duplicate pass generation? I mean, is there any chance that in future generator can create the activation key that already exists in db table? Should I check for duplication after key generation?

Comment: Unless you're using some insanely complicated key generator that requires a Top500 supercomputer to make the key, it should trivial to generate a key and check the db if it's been generated before.

Comment: Of course you run out of unique values sooner or later, but this doesn't matter since these are initial values and random, therfore quite secure. In fact we can't tell you how likely your algorith is to produce duplicates, because we don't know it at all. -- If you need to assert a value is not a duplicate you can test it for uniqueness, or use some random string plus timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php).

Comment: uniqid is a bad idea as it is not random at all and thus perfectly predictable.

Comment: Should be a non-issue if you make use of the $more_entropy argument.

Comment: Thx guys for help. Is this code secure enough? md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));

Comment: @simshaun That might be right. I don't know what it uses as entropy source. If you have a high quality entropy source available (/dev/random) you should use that. If not `md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true))` might need to do it.

Comment: Considering it's an activation key, I would say so. Also, keep in mind you could clear a user's activation key from the database once activated. Why the md5 hash though?

Comment: and one more thing, how long will be this key  md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));? Which type and length should I select for database column?

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu It's a CHAR(32) (you can also save it as a BINARY(16))

Comment: md5 hashes (in hexadecimal form) are 32 characters.

Comment: $stmt->bind_param("i", $actkey) or $stmt->bind_param("s", $actkey) ?

Comment: They are strings, not integers.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using the [Text_Password package](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Password) from PEAR.  Don't try to reinvent this wheel.

**Don't force passwords to be strictly unique.**  It's actually *less* secure to have that enforcement.  Consider that if I try to set my password to *xyzzy* and the site tells me I can't, that means now I know some account is using *xyzzy* as a password.  I just have to try that password on all accounts until I find which one.

**Don't use a hash digest as a generated password.**  Your users don't want to type in a hex string of 32 character (or longer).  I have had the experience of coding a secure software activation key package in 2001, using PKI and MD5 hashes.  But no one would use it because the keys were too long.

**Do use a hash digest and salt to store passwords.**  Read this article by our fearless leader:  [You're Probably Storing Passwords Incorrectly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html).

See also my answers to a few other password-related questions:

- [How to generate random password, or temporary URL, for resetting password in Zend Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754810/how-to-generate-random-password-or-temporary-url-for-resetting-password-in-zen/754869#754869)
- [PHP & MySQL compare password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488804/php-mysql-compare-password/488893#488893)
- [What data type to use for hashed password field and what length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247304/mysql-what-data-type-to-use-for-hashed-password-field-and-what-length/247627#247627)
- [How large should my password salt be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438243/how-large-should-my-password-salt-be/7438390#7438390)

Comment: Thx for fast reply, sir. Is this code secure enough? md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));

Comment: and one more thing, how long will be this key  md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));? Which type and length should I select for database column?

Comment: Am I missing something? I don't think he's generating a password. He's generating activation keys. (Text_Password can still be used for this though.)

Comment: Yeah, it's not an exact comparison, but they are similar enough that I think the best practices for password management are relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Using a hash algorithm like SHA or Whirlpool with a unique input (like the users' **unique** username) will result in a hash that has an expected collision rate of 0.

I wouldn't roll my own algorithm for this.  `uniqid()` or `md5()`, as mentioned, are guaranteed solutions.

Comment: `uniqid` is guaranteed, within the scope of your PHP installation, to generate a unique id, so theoretically, `uniqid` is better.  However, in practice, both are probably approximately the same.  *edit* I would say that code is "secure," but in this context, security isn't really a factor.  It will generate a unique result, but it's how you use it that makes it secure.

Comment: and one more thing, how long will be this key  md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));? Which type and length should I select for database column?

Comment: `md5()` hashes are 128 bits long.  You can use `char(128)` if you choose to use `md5()`.  See [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5).

Comment: @rockerest: You don't need 128 characters to store 128 bits.  It only requires 32 hex digits, or 16 binary bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the time, but it won't be "random" you'd have to add some randomness to it...

```
$key = md5(time());
```

Comment: md5 is not collision safe and your solution will actually generate the same activation key for some simultaneous registrations.

Comment: and one more thing, how long will be this key  md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));? Which type and length should I select for database column?

Comment: md5 returns a 32-length string, so varchar(32) is what you need for the table column

Answer (score 0):

Use GUID as your registration key, as it is always unique and generated by system